# Как заменить цвет текстуры?

Tags: c++, opengl

Имеется текстура с текстом. Сам текст белый, фон прозрачный. Как заменить цвет текста на любой?(не трогая альфа-канал).

```
void glUtils::DrawTexture(GLuint* tex, int w, int h, int cx, int cy){
    glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    glEnable(GL_BLEND);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, *tex);   
    float ut = 1, v =  1;
    float wt = w, ht = h;
    glBegin(GL_QUADS);
    glTexCoord2f(0, 0), glVertex2f(cx - wt / 2, cy + ht / 2);
    glTexCoord2f(ut, 0), glVertex2f(cx + wt / 2, cy + ht / 2);
    glTexCoord2f(ut, v), glVertex2f(cx + wt / 2, cy - ht / 2);
    glTexCoord2f(0, v), glVertex2f(cx - wt / 2, cy - ht / 2);
    glEnd();
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);
    glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);  
};
```

Такой вариант не работает. Текст не меняет цвета.

```
glColor4ub(255,0,0,255);
glUtils::DrawTexture(&tex, w, h, cx, cy);
```

Comment: glColor3f(1f, 0f, 0f) - красненький. Старый опенгл в таком случае умножит цвет на вашей текстуре на цвет вершины, умножаем белый на красный - получается красный

Comment: @selya - не меняется

Comment: Не знаю, как вы там делаете. Вот, попробуйте как тут: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6444851/opengl-texture-and-colors

Comment: @selya да я много примеров пересмотрел. Везде просто устанавливают цвет, и рисуют текстуру. А у меня не работает. Если отключить саму текстуру, то видно что объект(QUADS) меняет цвет, но сама текстура нет.

Comment: Может дело в самой текстуре?

Comment: Если дело не в текстуре, то, возможно, в том, как вы инициализируете OpenGL. Если покажете инициализацию, то, возможно, что-то станет ясно. К слову, OpenGL 1 очень-очень стар, так что не стоит использовать его в реальных проектах. Однако если вы только изучаете OpenGL, то никаких проблем

Answer (score 0):

Вот в чем было дело.   `glTexEnvi(GL_TEXTURE_ENV, GL_TEXTURE_ENV_MODE, GL_MODULATE);`